# How to make Edit Text hint disappear when typing?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have Edit Text field using which I take birthday.

I want to display `DD/MM/YYYY` the date format as a hint. Also I do NOT want it to disappear the moment that field is focused.

I want the hint text be replaced by the numbers while typing and when the numbers are deleted the hint text has to reappear. So that in the middle of typing the string would be like `25/04/1YYY`, `DD/11/1989` and so on.
How can I do this?

Comment: You need to implement the `TextWatcher` and implement it manually. No inbuilt methods are there for this functionality

Comment: I can help, but, I charge $150 per hour, although, if you post something you've done to achieve your goal and tell us where you are getting a problem, I can help you for free!

Comment: You could stick 3 edittext and 2 testviews in a linear layout and then change the focus based on the number of texts they entered

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
final EditText date = new EditText(this);
date .setHint("DD/MM/YYYY");
date .setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


                    date .setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            date .setText("");
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I require. This makes the mask disappear on touch. I want it to disappear character by character when each character is replaced by the typed number

Answer (score 0):

Here is the concept of text watcher you can take help from it

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        viewText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

         txtEdit.addTextChangedListener (new TextWatcher() {

              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                  Log.i("TC", "beforeTC " + s.toString() + " "
                          + s.subSequence(start, start + count).toString());
              }

              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                  Log.i("TC", "onTC " + s.toString() + " "
                          + s.subSequence(start, start + count).toString());
              }

              public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                  Log.i("TC", "afterTC " + s.toString());
              }
         });
    }
```